# Angular: Can't bind to 'visible' since it isn't a known property of 'Not Found Component'

Tags: angular, typescript, property-binding

I am trying to implement not found functionality to my Angular Frontend Project. It works on several components but it does not work in Event Page Component.

Here is the code from Not Found Component.

```
<div *ngIf="visible">
{{notFoundMessage}}
<a routerLink="{{resetLinkRoute}}">{{resetLinkText}}</a>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() visible: boolean = false;
  @Input() notFoundMessage: string = "Nothing Found!";
  @Input() resetLinkText: string = "Reset";
  @Input() resetLinkRoute: string = "/";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

When I try to bind it to Event Page Component like this:

```
<app-not-found 
[visible]="!event"
notFoundMessage="Event Not Found"
resetLinkText="Go To Homepage">
</app-not-found>

<div *ngIf="event" class="container"> ...  </div>
```

I am given this type of error:
[image]

Here is the app.module.ts
[image]

Can You help me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you added `NotFoundComponent` to a module?

Comment: Without example code to reproduce the issue, the error message you're receiving means that Angular can't find `NotFoundComponent` in the module the "Event Page Component" is located in.

Comment: Have you got more than one module in your project? Can you show us the content of your app.module.ts?

Comment: You're missing the `CommonModule` which adds support for structural directives

Comment: You need CommonModule

Comment: I have BrowserModule which contains it.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped. As posted it should work. I suggest try reloading environment. May be helpful to see examples where it *does* work in your code to see if that helps identify what the difference is